# Shell - Recursively find sub-directories and copy containing files to another directory

Tags: linux, shell, unix, find, xargs

I have got the following directory-/file structure:

```
/test
     /dir_a
         /dir_pic
             car.jpg
             train.jpg
             thumbs.db
     /dir_b
         /dir_pic
             car.jpg
             plane.jpg
             boat.jpg
     /dir_c
         /dir_pic
             ship.jpg
             space_shuttle.jpg
```

I would like to copy the files creating the following structure:

```
 /test2
     /c
         /car
             car.jpg
     /b
         /boat
             boat.jpg
     /p
         /plane
             plane.jpg
     /s
         /ship
             ship.jpg
         /space shuttle
             space shuttle.jpg
     /t
         /train
             train.jpg
```

I created the sub-directories with `for i in {a..z}; do mkdir ordner${i}; done`, 
but I don't know how to create the sub-directories and how to copy the files. 
I tried something like `find /test/ -type d -name ".dir_pic" | xargs -0 -I%%% cp %%%/${i}*.jpg /test2/`, but that doesn't work. 
Apart from that for-loops don't work, especially when the path contains blanks ?

As my Linux-knowledge is quite limited I would kindly ask for your help how to realize this (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

Comment: why `train.jpg` is missed?

Comment: just a typing error

Comment: another moment is that `dir_a` and `dir_b` both contain `car.jpg` files which could different images. Which one should be chosen and why?

Comment: Yes, I have intentionally added this entry two times in the example as in reality there also will be identical files. The content of the files will be the same, so it could be overwritten or ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**bash** solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

dest_dir="/test2"         # destination directory

for f in $(find /test/ -type f -path "*/dir_pic/*.jpg"); do 
    fn="${f##*/}"         # filename (basename)
    parent_d="${fn:0:1}"  # parent directory
    child_d="${fn%.*}"    # child directory

    if [[ ! -d "$dest_dir/$parent_d/$child_d" ]]; then
        mkdir -p "$dest_dir/$parent_d/$child_d"
        cp "$f" "$dest_dir/$parent_d/$child_d/$fn" 
    fi
done
```

---

Viewing results:

```
$ tree /test2
|-- b
|   `-- boat
|       `-- boat.jpg
|-- c
|   `-- car
|       `-- car.jpg
|-- p
|   `-- plane
|       `-- plane.jpg
|-- s
|   |-- ship
|   |   `-- ship.jpg
|   `-- space_shuttle
|       `-- space_shuttle.jpg
|-- t
|   `-- train
|       `-- train.jpg
```

Comment: Question, Why only `mkdir` and `cp` if neither the directory or file exists? Wouldn't it be equivalent to simply call `mkdir -p` on each subdir (no error if it already exists) and then a `cp -ua` to copy the latest version (or while `$child_d"` exists, add an incremental number, e.g. `name_01.ext`, and copy that file)?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, for identical files in different folders - the OP said *it could be overwritten or ignored*. So that condition was to create/copy the needed folders/files at once without playing with incrementing or generating `name_01.ext`

Comment: I liked the solution. I guess if he isn't concerned, no concern was warranted. Good job.

Comment: That's perfect! 

I didn't know the option `-path` for the `find`-command. 
Furthermore I added a `IFS=$'\n'` at the beginning resp. a `unset IFS
` at the end of the script, so files whose path contain a blank character a treated successfully. 
Thank you very much!